# JQuery Plugin which can work same as PHP Excel

Tags: jquery, excel, plugins

I am in search of any JQuery Plugin **like PHP Excel** which can be able to handle some of the functionality like the PHP Excel Lib do.

Answer (score 0):

how about [this](http://kayalshri.github.io/tableExport.jquery.plugin/) plugin

According to documentation this plugin can export a html table to following files

1. JSON
2. XML
3. PNG
4. CSV
5. TXT
6. SQL
7. MS-Word
8. Ms-Excel
9. Ms-Powerpoint
10. PDF

Comment: Well thanks for the reply but this plugin will not work out for me. As I need both uploading and downloading.

Comment: then why haven't you mentioned this in question? also y doesn't this plugin workout for u? for downloading use this plugin and for uploading use some other plugin.

Comment: Hi sorry, if you felt bad. I did mentioned in my question that I need Plugin equivalent to PHP Excel. Please read the question.

Comment: but your plugin is really good for downloading tables in multiple format it will be useful for me.

Comment: PHP Excel handles file uploading? i think still i am not sure of what you want

Comment: please read the title properly **"JQuery Plugin which can work same as PHP Excel"**.

Comment: PHP Excel is for server side scripting and jQuery is for client side scripting. so, how can you expect the phpexcel to be in jQuery?